# Can't install windows 10 on VMWare Player

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, vmware-player

I tried 3 different versions of windows, and 2 different versions of vm, booting from iso and dvd and every one of them stuck at some phase of the installation.

Every time when it tries to reboot after finishing a phase (like preparing files), the loading screen remains for 6 hours (when i restart the vm), sometimes the loading circle moving, sometimes frozen. The task manager shows 100% processor usage and some ram usage. I'd be very grateful for any help, need the program installed for university for tomorrow. Pls help.

This one was running for 5 hours and stuck at installing windows updates:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jk9Bpn7cwPXJHw951gjxaNm4aZPAB--h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: VMware Workstation is paid software, it should come with some form of support. Have you tried contacting them regarding this issue?

Comment: I'm using the free version. I posted this question on their forum.

Comment: I don't know how you installed VMware Player, but the log shows that it doesn't have any permissions on the folders it needs to update.

Comment: Ty, what can cause this? I installed and used it as admin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the processor is unable to support Windows 10 on VMWare Player.

Windows 10 configuration requirements(the minimum)

**Processor:** 1Ghz or faster (PAE,NX and SSE2 supported)

**The memory module:** 1GB(32bit), 2GB(64bit)

**Display card:** Microsoft DirectX9 graphics device with WDDM driver

**Hard disk space:**

Equal to or greater than 16GB (32bit),

Equal to or greater than 20GB (64bit)

**Operating system:**

Microsoft Windows 10 64bit,

Microsoft Windows 10 32bit

1. We can try to check our computer configuration.
2. Also, check to see if the virtualization capabilities of the processor are enabled in the BIOS.